# What is the difference between \1 and $1 in a Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

What is the difference of doing \1 as opposed to $1 if any, or are they interchangeable in all situations.

Example:

```
s/([a-z]+),afklol/$1,bck/;
#against
s/([a-z]+),afklol/\1,bck/;
```

They both give the same result but is there any difference?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Straight from [perldoc perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241):

> Warning on \1 vs $1
>
> Some people get too used to writing
>   things like:
>
> ```
> $pattern =~ s/(\W)/\\\1/g;
> ```
>
> This is grandfathered for the RHS of a
>   substitute to avoid shocking the sed
>   addicts, but it’s a dirty habit to get
>   into.  That’s because in PerlThink,
>   the righthand side of an "s///" is a
>   double- quoted string.  "\1" in the
>   usual double-quoted string means a
>   control-A.  The customary Unix meaning
>   of "\1" is kludged in for "s///". 
>   However, if you get into the habit of
>   doing that, you get yourself into
>   trouble if you then add an "/e"
>   modifier.
>
> ```
> s/(\d+)/ \1 + 1 /eg;        # causes warning under -w
> ```
>
> Or if you try to do
>
> ```
> s/(\d+)/\1000/;
> ```
>
> You can’t disambiguate that by saying
>   "{1}000", whereas you can fix it with
>   "${1}000".  The operation of
>   interpolation should not be confused
>   with the operation of matching a
>   backreference.
>
> Certainly they mean two different
>   things on the left side of the "s///".

Answer (score 11):

I only use `\1` on the rare occasions where I need the match to include a repeat of an earlier part of the pattern. e.g.

```
/(foo|bar)baz\1/
```

This would match "foobazfoo" or "barbazbar" but not "foobazbar". You *can't* use `$1` there.

In all other circumstances I use `$1` and kin, because there are too many gotchas to using the other notation. See [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) for all the gory details.

Comment: That's what I was wondering when I saw the question: can they both be used for back-reference?

Answer (score 1):

They give the same result, but $1 retains its value while \1 does not. Try this:

```
s/([a-z]+),afklol/$1,bck/;
print "\$1 is $1\n";
#against
s/([a-z]+),afklol/\1,bck/;
print "\\1 is \1\n";
```

Comment: That's because outside of a m// or s/// \1 isn't a back-reference. (What it actually is depends on the context.)