# Notepad++ Replace regex match for same text plus appending character

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a file with text and numbers with a length of five (i.e. `12000`, `11153`, etc.). I want to append all of these numbers with a `0`. So `11153` becomes `111530`. Is this possible in Notepad++?

I know I can find all numbers with the following regex: `[0-9]{5}`, but how can I replace these with the same number, plus an appending `0`?

In the replacement box I tried the following things:

- `[0-9]{5}0` - Which it took literally, so `11153` was replaced with `[0-9]{5}0`
- `\10`  - I read somewhere that `\1` would take the match, but it doesn't seem to work. This will replace `11153` with `0`
- EDIT: `\00` - Based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19575551/1682559) I see I need to use `\0` instead of `\1`. It still doesn't work though. This will replace `11153` with

So, I've got the feeling I'm close with the `\1` or `\0`, but not close enough.

Comment: `^[0-9]{5}$` (or `\b[0-9]{5}\b`) --> `${0}0`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You are very near to the answer! What you missed is a capturing group.

Use this regex in "Find what" section:

`([0-9]{5})`

In "Replace with", use this:

`\10`

The `(` and `)` represent a capturing group. This essentially means that you capture your number, and then replace it with the same followed by a zero.

Comment: You do not need to capture at all, all OP needs is a `\d{5}` (or `\b\d{5}\b`, or `^\d{5}$`) --> `${0}0`, just use a 0th group defined with the Perl-like backreference. The use of the POSIX style backreference requires the use of a capturing group, true (as POSIX backreferences start from `1` to `9`, thus `\10` is never mistaken for the backreference to the 10th group).

Comment: In my case I don't need the last `0` of `\10`.
I just only do capture group with bracket and use `\1` for replacing the capture group text to make result of replacing same as search capture group.

Comment: On VSCode, `$10` is what worked for me. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43577528/1169233

Answer (score 9):

You are very close. You need to add a capturing group to your regex by surrounding it with brackets. `([0-9]{5})`

Then use `\10` as the replacement. This is replacing the match with the text from group 1 followed by a zero.

Comment: No problem. I'm just not fast enough :). I'm glad you have the solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`\K` to reset](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K).

```
\b\d{5}\b\K
```

And replace with `0`

- `\b` matches a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `\d` is a [short](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for digit `[0-9]`

[See demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sH5hZ4/1)

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in Notepad++, but when I use your regex and use Find Next it does find all the numbers, but when I click the replace with `0`, it doesn't append the 0..

Comment: @KevinCruijssen: Just checked, zeros are added (v.6.9).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen I tested it with my np++ v6.8.8 where it worked : )

Comment: When I use Replace All it does indeed work, but when I use Find Next + Replace it doesn't (Notepad++ v6.9). Ah well, I need to replace everything anyway, so +1 as well. I've accept _HappyCoder_'s answer though. As always with regex, there are a lot of different ways to solve the same issue.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen that's fine, up to you which answer prefer : ) in my np++ also the "find next" works (zero length matches as supposed to).

Answer (score 0):

General case:

```
Find what:    (?<=left)(.*?)(?=right)
Replace with: left_append\1right_append
Wrap around [x]
```

so e.g.

```
fast=false, out_loc='file',
category=9%s!d,
-->
fast={false}, out_loc={'file'},
category={9%s!d},
```

i.e. append `{` and `}` between `=` and `,`, is accomplished with

```
(?<==)(.*?)(?=,)
\{\1\}
```

with escaping as appropriate. [Regex further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23756210/10133797).