# Visual Studio Code Search and Replace with Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I want to use "Search And Replace" in Visual Studio Code to change every instance of  `<h1>content</h1>` to `#### content` within a document using a Regular Expression.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Does it have to be a regex find and replace? Could you just replace `<h4>` with `#### ` and then replace `</h4>` with `''`?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

So, your goal is to search and replace?
According to Visual Studio Code's keyboard shortcuts PDF, you can press **<kbd>Ctrl + H</kbd>** on [Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-windows.pdf) and [Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf), or **<kbd>⌥⌘F</kbd>** on [Mac](https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf) to enable the search and replace tool:

[image: Visual studio code's search & replace tab]
If you mean to disable the code, you just have to put `<h1>` in search, and replace to `####`.

But if you want to use this regex instead, you may enable it in the icon: <sub><sub><sub>[image: .*]</sub></sub></sub> and use the regex: `<h1>(.+?)<\/h1>` and replace to: `#### $1`.

And as [@tpartee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227571/tpartee) suggested, here is some more information about Visual Studio's engine if you would like to learn more:

- [Find and Replace Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wdd0wk1.aspx) *(documentation)*
- [Quick Replace, Find and Replace Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87a13zt0.aspx) *(documentation)*
- [What flavor of Regex does Visual Studio Code use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179046/what-flavor-of-regex-does-visual-studio-code-use/42184299#42184299)

Comment: Visual Studio will handle the regex like every other application, the only difference is the so-called regex flavors, which is the 'compiler' of the regex and how will it treat the expression. Usually, it's ignored in answers like these because most of them are pretty similar, but for those who still want to check it out, I've added it to the answer

Comment: The question is about Visual Studio Code, and this answer is about Visual Studio.

Comment: or change your Keybindings. Example: By IDEA Keybindings (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings) you could use: Ctrl+Shift+R for Replace in Path or for Find In Path: Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: It works for me. I need to replace image reference in 100 places from a folder abc to xyz. I used below FIND: \/abc\/(.+?).gif     replace: /xyz/$1.gif

Answer (score 101):

For beginners, I wanted to add to the accepted answer, because a couple of subtleties were unclear to me:

To find and *modify* text (not completely replace),

1. In the "Find" step, you can use regex with "capturing groups," e.g. your search could be `la la la (group1) blah blah (group2)`, using parentheses.
2. And then in the "Replace" step, you can refer to the capturing groups via `$1`, `$2` etc.

So, for example, in this case we could *find* the relevant text with just `<h1>.+?<\/h1>` (no parentheses), but putting in the parentheses `<h1>(.+?)<\/h1>` allows us to refer to the sub-match in between them as `$1` in the *replace* step.  Cool!

Notes

- To turn on Regex in the Find Widget, click the `.*` icon, or press `Cmd/Ctrl` `Alt` `R`
- `$0` refers to the whole match
- Finally, the original question states that the replace should happen "within a document," so you can use the "Find Widget" (`Cmd` or `Ctrl` + `F`), which is local to the open document, instead of "Search", which opens a bigger UI and looks across all files in the project.

Comment: Online regex tools are also very helpful to beginners for writing the regex in the first place. Also, use find with your regex to make sure it's actually getting what you want and **manually replace the first few entries before you replace all** to make sure the result is what you think it is.

Comment: Adding on to @silvertiger, here are two editors I use on a day to day: https://regex101.com, https://regexr.com

Answer (score 13):

If you want for example, change all country codes in `.json` file from uppercase to lowercase:

```
Ctrl+h
Alt+r
Alt+c

Find: ([A-Z]{2,})
Replace: $1

Alt+Enter
F1
type: lower -> select toLowerCase
Ctrl+Alt+Enter
```

example file:

```
[
  {"id": "PL", "name": "Poland"},
  {"id": "NZ", "name": "New Zealand"},
  ...
]
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP, but I came here from google search and that works... but how?

Ctrl + H - Open replacement window. Not really necessary, can be Ctrl + F.
Alt + R - toggle regex.
Alt + C - toggle case matching.

Alt+Enter - Search Editor: Open Results in Editor. This is where the magic happens, it selects **ALL** occurrences of the search phrase in the document.
F1 - Open command palette.
Ctrl + Alt + Enter - Not sure what it does, you can just press enter.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Match Case is selected with Use Regular Expression so this matches. [A-Z]* 
If match case is not selected, this matches all letters.