# VSCode wildcard Search and Replace Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to do a project wide search and replace

from:

```
drivers[i].findElement(By.id("elementID")).click();
```

to:

```
findAndClick(driver[i], "elementID", true)
```

The issue is the elementID can be anything so I'm trying to wildcard search and replace with what's in the wildcard?

[image]

Comment: These are not wildcards, that is a regex. You need to escape `[`, `(`, `)` and to match any chars, use `.*` or `.*?`.

Comment: I tried this but got nothing: `drivers[i].findElement(By.id[(".*?")])].click[()]`

Comment: I also forgot to mention dots: `drivers\[i]\.findElement\(By\.id\(".*?"\)\)\.click\(\);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio Code Search and Replace with Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577528/visual-studio-code-search-and-replace-with-regular-expressions)

Comment: yes that answers my question, thank you

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You'll need to use `.+?` instead of `*` here since this uses regular expressions.

In regular expressions a dot `.` means "any character", the plus `+` means "one or more times", and the question mark `?` after this means "try to match this as few as possible times" - which is useful so it won't keep matching past your quote marks

### edit

To be clear though, you have to make a valid regex, which means you'll need to escape your parenthesis, dots, etc.

Here's the full solution

**Find**: `drivers\[i\]\.findElement\(By\.id\("(.+?)"\)\)\.click\(\);`

**replace with:** `findAndClick(driver[i], "$1", true)`

Note the added *unescaped* parentheses in there around the "wildcard" `(.+)` this creates a capture group in a regex, which is what translates to `$1` in the replacement since it's the 1st capture group.

Comment: This gives me an error `drivers[i].findElement(By.id(".+")).click();`

Comment: One does not have to escape `]` outside of the character class.

Comment: `(.+?)` surrounding parenthesis are must. I had missed those at first

Comment: I only had to use `.` instead of `.+?`, both gave me the same result.