# Which is the quickest way to copy Footer information from one RDl to another. I have 45-50 RDL's to update with footer

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have may RDL's to update with there footer information for my client. I have almost 45-50 RDL's to update with footer information.
Which is the best way to copy paste the code from one RDL to another or any other method that suits me to do it within less time.

I tried using copying the footer information from the code to the another code.  But giving me error such as below

"More than one report item in the report has the name 'Textbox3'. Report item names must be unique within a report. "

The goal is to achieve this within less time and customizing the SSRS design page using alternatives .But its not working. Please help me the unique ideas.Thanks

Comment: I think you should just change the name of the table to something unique, like `TBFooter1`.

Comment: Assuming that the old footers contain the same text, you could open your rdl files with an editor like notepad++ and then use replace string to change it to all files

Comment: You could get all the RDL files in a folder, open that folder with Visual Studio Code (other good editors probably can do the same) then use search and replace in files (Shift+Ctrl+F in windows) but search with a regex expression. A similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43577528/visual-studio-code-search-and-replace-with-regular-expressions . As hannover suggested though, change the footer you want to copy to have uniquely named textboxes (or whatever objects are in the footer)