# What Is The Character For A Wildcard While Searching In VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm deobfuscating some code and I forget the operator to use a wildcard while searching for text in VSCode. By this I mean in VSCode whenever you search for code (CMD/CTRL + F), what is the character for a wild card (*i.e* searching for "date{WILDCARD HERE}" would return "date1","date2","date", etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recall a wildcard option (I've never used it at least).  But the [search feature supports using regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43578165/6530134).

Given your examples of *date1, date2, date,* etc. assuming it followed a pattern of `date<n>` where `n` is a number (or nothing in the case of just "date"), the regular expression of `date[1-9]*` should achieve what you want.

You can test the expression out on [this site](https://regex101.com/).  Input the regular expression and some sample data and see how it matches.