# Notepad++ Search and Replace for Value Between Tags

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

Question title is confusing and if anyone has a better way to word it I'm all ears

I'm looking for a way to replace the following

```
<option>value</option>
```

with

```
<option value="value">value</option>
```

I have about 200 of these that I'd have to do by hand otherwise and as they say laziness is the great inventor of easy solutions

Does anyone know if this is possible with find and replace or anything else?

Thanks!

- Zach

Edited to reflect the possible duplicate: The answered question over there does not necessarily explain what it is doing in my opinion (they used a ([]{}) solution instead of just the capture group, and it was not easily findable  VIA google, which I think this question is more easily searchable)

Comment: It's possible for sure. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Well I've made it this far where I have the <option>value</option> tags around it using regular expressions (\n and \r), but I don't know how to put the value between the tags into the replace field, so if I were to try I would say


    Find: <option>
    Replace: <option value=".*<">

but that doesn't do anything except replace the <option> with <option value="*.<">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Notepad++ Replace regex match for same text plus appending character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983330/notepad-replace-regex-match-for-same-text-plus-appending-character)

Comment: Similar question but different usage, either way I couldn't find this via Google before, thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a capture group.  You want

find:

```
<option>(.*?)</option>
```

replace:

```
<option $1="$1">$1</option>
```

The `()` denotes your first (and only) capture group and `$1` refers to it in the replace.  Obviously you should replace `$1` if you want the word "value" literally.

Comment: I used this except I modified it to 
Find:
    <option>(.*>)

Replace:

    <option value="$1">

Then I went through and found and replaced each occurence of >" with " to fix my own issue (I misread your answer the first time)

Thank you guys!

Comment: @ZachHandley - The linked answer is actually very similar, although it uses `\1` to refer to the capture group, which I understand is deprecated in most newer regex engines.  `[]` is very standard stuff.  Check out https://regexone.com/ when you have a few free minutes.  Definitely worth the time.