# Simple Regex not working in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a simple Perl regex that should match a space between two characters and replace the space with a `*`.  It's simply not working in some cases.  The Perl line is this:

```
s/([A-Za-z0-9])\s+([A-Za-z0-9])/\1 * \2/g;
```

For example see below:  (`~>` is my zsh prompt)

```
~> cat mwe
s t Subscript[r, 1]
~> perl -pe "s/([A-Za-z0-9])\s+([A-Za-z0-9])/\1 * \2/g;" < mwe
s * t Subscript[r, 1]
```

`t Subscript[r, 1]` isn't being matched. This is just an example. My file is much longer, and while the regex catches most correctly, I can't find a pattern to the ones it doesn't match (and should).

Vim seems to find everything correctly (after the appropriate regex syntax changes).

How can I go about solving this? How can I help diagnose the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `s Subscript`: can't be matched, as you matched `t s` just before, so the `s` is already "consumed" and no longer looked at... You'll need another pass to get that one. Same thing for the last `t subScript` : the `t` was used in the preceding replacement and the next search starts after it. You could take out the 'g' and instead loop until there is no replacement anymore.

Comment: Don't use \1 and \2 in the replacement expression. \1 and \2 only make sense in a regex pattern since they mean match what the first and second capture captured. Use $1 and $2 instead.

Comment: @ikegami But I *want* what the first and second capture captured. (I'm not calling you wrong - the \1 vs $1 is something I'm obviously confused about)

Comment: I know, but that's not what I said. You dropped the word "match" from what I said. You want "[to interpolate] what the first and second capture captured", which is different than wanting to "match what the first and second capture captured"

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the warning. I found more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068840/what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-1-in-a-perl-regex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lookahead instead:

```
perl -pe 's/([a-z0-9])\s+(?=[a-z0-9])/\1 * /ig' mwe
```

**Output:**

> s-E^(t * Subscript[r, 1]) t * v-E^(t * Subscript[r, 1]) y-E^(t *
>   Subscript[r, 1]) t * y+E^t * s * Subscript[r, 1]+2 * E^(t *
>   Subscript[r, 1]) s * Subscript[r, 1]-3 * E^(t+t * Subscript[r, 1]) s *
>   Subscript[r, 1]+E^(t * Subscript[r, 1]) s * t * Subscript[r, 1]

Problem is that in your regex you're matching not looking ahead. So for the case of:

```
perl -pe 's/([a-z0-9])\s+([a-z0-9])/\1 * \2/ig' <<< "a b c"
```

You will get:

```
a * b c
```

Since `b` has already been matched previously and internal pointer has moved ahead.

Comment: Okay thank you.  While this works, could you please tell me why mine doesn't work?

Comment: A lookahead does not change the position of the regex match, so the left parenthesis can match the `t` the second time. Without the lookahead, the `t` is consumed in the first match.

Comment: regex is "lazy" it doesn't stop on the first match, it looks for the last possible match, so I believe in your case, it will stop before it reaches the point you are looking for

Comment: @bkanuka: I added some explanation to my answer.

Comment: +1, nice solution. It's close to the original, and shows when to use the lookahead.