# perl Multiline Find and Replace with regex

Tags: regex, perl, multiline

I have a properties file `test.properties` with some content like shown:

```
#DEV
#jms_value=devdata.example
#TST
#jms_value=tstdata.example
#DEV
#ems_value=emsdev.example
```

I want to uncomment the line under the environment name based on the environment where the file goes.

If the file goes to DEV environment. I need the line under the all '#DEV' need to be uncommented. I have used the following command:

```
perl -i -p -e 's/#DEV\n#(.*)/#DEV\n\1/g;' test.properties
```

This is not changing anything in the file.

Can anyone help me in finding a solution for this?

Comment: By default the perl command line read the input (a file or from a pipe) line by line. With this condition, you can't obviously use a multiline pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to slurp the entire file, from [perlrun doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

> The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode.
>   Any value 0400 or above will cause Perl to slurp files whole, but by
>   convention the value 0777 is the one normally used for this purpose.

I have slightly modified sample input for demonstration:

```
$ cat ip.txt 
#DEV
#jms_value=devdata.example
#TST
#jms_value=tstdata.example
#DEV
#ems_value=emsdev.example
xyz #DEV
#abc
```

Adding `-0777` option to OP's regex

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/#DEV\n#(.*)/#DEV\n\1/g' ip.txt 
#DEV
jms_value=devdata.example
#TST
#jms_value=tstdata.example
#DEV
ems_value=emsdev.example
xyz #DEV
abc
```

If `#DEV` has to be matched at start of line only, use `m` flag

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/^#DEV\n#(.*)/#DEV\n\1/mg' ip.txt 
#DEV
jms_value=devdata.example
#TST
#jms_value=tstdata.example
#DEV
ems_value=emsdev.example
xyz #DEV
#abc
```

Positive lookbehind can be used as well:

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/^#DEV\n\K#//mg' ip.txt 
#DEV
jms_value=devdata.example
#TST
#jms_value=tstdata.example
#DEV
ems_value=emsdev.example
xyz #DEV
#abc
```

**Also note:** [What is the difference between \1 and $1 in a Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068840/what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-1-in-a-perl-regex)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a variable as a flag. If you see `#DEV`, set it to 1, otherwise set it to 0. Remove the leading `#` if the flag is set - but check the flag before setting it!

```
perl -pe 's/^#// if $delete; $delete = /^#DEV$/;' input-file
```

Comment: Again @choroba please describe the problem that your answer solves. Your effort serves only the OP, and only then if your analysis is correct. That isn't the way Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @Borodin: My answer tries to solve the problem asked in the question: how to uncomment the environment name and the following line for a given environment name.

Comment: @Borodin: Sorry, it should have been "how to uncomment the line following the given environment name".

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
perl -pe'if ($a==1) {s/^#//;$a=0;} $a=1 if (/^#DEV/)'
```