# perl one liner inside python script

Tags: python, perl

I have a perl one liner that appends a string at the end of a particular line and it works when I run the one liner on the host. For instance, I'm looking to append 'boy857sr xxxxxxx' at the end of a line that starts with 'AllowUsers'

```
perl -pi.bak -e 's/^(AllowUsers.*)/\1 boy857sr xxxxxxx/g;' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Works perfectly!

```
AllowUsers boy857bt soladmin svc-Orion_SAM solarw boy857lj boy806nk boy806sk   boy857sr xxxxxxx
```

But when I run it inside a python script, it wipes out the 'AllowUsers' line and add another line, look below:

```
#RSAAuthentication yes
^A kn857sr xxxxxxx
```

Here is the python script.

```
import pxssh

my_list=[
"server121"
]


for i in my_list:
    s = pxssh.pxssh(timeout=15, maxread=2000000)
    s.SSH_OPTS += "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
    s.SSH_OPTS += "-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null"
    s.login(i,'username','password')
    print (i)

    s.sendline('/usr/local/bin/sudo su -')
    s.expect('Password: ')
    s.sendline('xxxxxxx')

    s.prompt()
    print s.before
    s.sendline('perl -pi.bak -e \'s/^(AllowUsers.*)/\1 boy857sr xxxxxxx/g;\' 
/etc/ssh/sshd_config')
    s.prompt()
    print s.before

    s.sendline('exit')
    s.logout()
```

Comment: Actually I also wonder why _your_ post isn't upvoted some more. It is one of the few questions a day with a clear problem statement **and** a nice [mcve]! I wish there were more of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python interprets the `\1` in your replacement string as the character 0x01 (which often renders as `^A`).

Moreover, using `\1`, `\2` etc. in Perl regexes is reserved to the left hand side of the `s///` operator, i.e. to the *pattern*. On the right hand side (the replacement string) you should use `$1`, `$2` etc. instead.

From the [docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Gory-details-of-parsing-quoted-constructs)

> ... It is at this step that `\1` is begrudgingly converted to `$1` in
>   the replacement text of `s///`, in order to correct the incorrigible
>   sed hackers who haven't picked up the saner idiom yet. A warning is
>   emitted if the `use warnings` pragma or the `-w` command-line flag
>   (that is, the `$^W` variable) was set.

So:

```
s.sendline('perl -pi.bak -e \'s/^(AllowUsers.*)/$1 boy857sr xxxxxxx/g;\' /etc/ssh/sshd_config')
```

should do the trick.

---

**Update**: Eventually I found the [reference page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241) for `\1` vs. `$1` (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1068840/5830574)).

Comment: @BioRod Glad to hear. I have no idea and wondered myself. Perhaps someone misclicked.

Comment: @BioRod If it worked, shouldn't you accept this answer?

Comment: @BioRod Tickle the gray hook below the downvote arrow with your mouse. If you agree with the hover-help, then click. But don't hurry. Take your time. It's ok if you decide later.