# Delete spaces around specific tags in an html file in shell

Tags: html, sed

I'm looking to write a shell script that minify less html files, but I'm having a problem.

I would like to delete the space on each side of a specific html tag, these tags being read from a file. With "perl", I can't do it, nothing happens, with sed in 2 commands I almost get what I want. In the example below, the space between some tags is removed, but not all, at the level of the "section" tags there is a problem, "h2" too, however the pattern matches ...

```
for tag in $tag_file ; do 
    #   perl -e '$comHtml=<>; $comHtml=~s/ *(<${tag} *.* *>) */\1/g; print $comHtml' < tmp_html
    sed -i -r -e "s: *(<${tag} *.* *>) *:\1:gI" ./tmp_html
    sed -i -r -e "s: *(</${tag} *.* *>) *:\1:gI" ./tmp_html
    done
```

here, $tag_file contains the specific tag got from a file, for example $tag_file = html \n head \n section \n ...

Entry html :

```
<!doctype html> <html lang="fr"> <head> <meta charset="UTF-8"> <title>La gazette de L-INFO</title> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/gazette.css"> </head> <body> <nav> <ul> <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li> <li><a href="./html/actus.html">Toute l'actu</a></li> <li><a href="./php/recherche.php">Recherche</a></li> <li><a href="./html/redaction.html">La rédac'</a></li> <li><a href="#">jbigoude</a> <ul> <li><a href="./php/compte.php">Mon profil</a></li> <li><a href="./php/nouveau.php">Nouvel article</a></li> <li><a href="./php/deconnexion.php">Se déconnecter</a></li> </ul> </li> </ul> </nav> <header> <img src="./images/titre.png" alt="La gazette de L-INFO" width="780" height="83"> <h1>Le site de désinformation n°1 des étudiants en Licence Info</h1> </header> <main> <section class="centre"> <h2>&Agrave; la Une</h2> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/hacker.jpg" alt="Un mouchard dans un corrigé de Langages du Web"><br> Un mouchard dans un corrigé de Langages du Web </a> <a href="./html/article.html"> <img src="images/hymne.jpg" alt="Votez pour l'hymne de la Licence"><br> Votez pour l'hymne de la Licence </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/melenchon.jpg" alt="L'amphi Sciences Naturelles bientôt renommé amphi Mélenchon"><br> L'amphi Sciences Naturelles bientôt renommé amphi Mélenchon </a> </section> <section class="centre"> <h2>L'info brûlante</h2> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/walkingdead.jpg" alt="Il avait annoncé 'Je vais vous défoncer' l'enseignant relaxé"><br> Il leur avait annoncé "Je vais vous défoncer" l'enseignant relaxé </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/pingouins.jpg" alt="Des pinguoins dans l'amphi B"><br> Toute une famille de pingouins découverte dans l'amphi B </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/macron.jpg" alt="Emmanuel Macron obtient sa Licence d'Info en EAD"><br> Emmanuel Macron obtient sa Licence Info en EAD </a> </section> <section class="centre"> <h2>Les incontournables</h2> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/arnaque.jpg" alt="Arnaque au devoir corrigé de TLSP"><br> Une arnarque au corrigé de TL mise à jour </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/calendrier.jpg" alt="Le calendier des Dieux de la Licence bientôt disponible"><br> Le calendier des Dieux de la Licence bientôt disponible </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/sondage.jpg" alt="Allez-vous réussir votre année ?"><br> Résultat de notre sondage : allez-vous réussir votre année ? </a> </section> <section> <h2>Horoscope de la semaine</h2> <p>Vous l'attendiez tous, voici l'horoscope du semestre pair de l'année 2019-2020. Sans surprise, il n'est pas terrible...</p> <table id="horoscope"> <tr> <td>Signe</td> <td>Date</td> <td>Votre horoscope</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&#9800; Bélier</td> <td>du 21 mars<br>au 19 avril</td> <td rowspan="4"> <p>Après des vacances bien méritées, l'année reprend sur les chapeaux de roues. Tous les signes sont concernés. </p> <p>Jupiter s'aligne avec Saturne, péremptoirement à Venus, et nous promet un semestre qui ne sera pas de tout repos. Février sera le mois le plus tranquille puisqu'il ne comporte que 29 jours.</p> <p>Les fins de mois seront douloureuses pour les natifs du 2e décan au moment où tomberont les tant-attendus résultats du module d'<em>Algorithmique et Structures de Données</em> du semestre 3.</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>&#9801; Taureau</td> <td>du 20 avril<br>au 20 mai</td> </tr> <tr> <td>...</td> <td>...</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&#9811; Poisson</td> <td>du 20 février<br>au 20 mars</td> </tr> </table> <p>Malgré cela, notre équipe d'astrologues de choc vous souhaite à tous un bon semestre, et bon courage pour le module de <em>Système et Programmation Système</em>.</p> </section> </main> <footer>&copy; Licence Informatique - Janvier 2020 - Tous droits réservés</footer> </body> </html>
```

output html :

```
<!doctype html><html lang="fr"><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>La gazette de L-INFO</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/gazette.css"></head><body><nav><ul> <li><a href="#">Accueil</a></li> <li><a href="./html/actus.html">Toute l'actu</a></li> <li><a href="./php/recherche.php">Recherche</a></li> <li><a href="./html/redaction.html">La rédac'</a></li> <li><a href="#">jbigoude</a> <ul> <li><a href="./php/compte.php">Mon profil</a></li> <li><a href="./php/nouveau.php">Nouvel article</a></li> <li><a href="./php/deconnexion.php">Se déconnecter</a></li></ul> </li> </ul></nav><header> <img src="./images/titre.png" alt="La gazette de L-INFO" width="780" height="83"><h1>Le site de désinformation n°1 des étudiants en Licence Info</h1></header><main><section class="centre"><h2>&Agrave; la Une</h2> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/hacker.jpg" alt="Un mouchard dans un corrigé de Langages du Web"><br> Un mouchard dans un corrigé de Langages du Web </a> <a href="./html/article.html"> <img src="images/hymne.jpg" alt="Votez pour l'hymne de la Licence"><br> Votez pour l'hymne de la Licence </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/melenchon.jpg" alt="L'amphi Sciences Naturelles bientôt renommé amphi Mélenchon"><br> L'amphi Sciences Naturelles bientôt renommé amphi Mélenchon </a></section> <section class="centre"> <h2>L'info brûlante</h2> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/walkingdead.jpg" alt="Il avait annoncé 'Je vais vous défoncer' l'enseignant relaxé"><br> Il leur avait annoncé "Je vais vous défoncer" l'enseignant relaxé </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/pingouins.jpg" alt="Des pinguoins dans l'amphi B"><br> Toute une famille de pingouins découverte dans l'amphi B </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/macron.jpg" alt="Emmanuel Macron obtient sa Licence d'Info en EAD"><br> Emmanuel Macron obtient sa Licence Info en EAD </a> </section> <section class="centre"> <h2>Les incontournables</h2> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/arnaque.jpg" alt="Arnaque au devoir corrigé de TLSP"><br> Une arnarque au corrigé de TL mise à jour </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/calendrier.jpg" alt="Le calendier des Dieux de la Licence bientôt disponible"><br> Le calendier des Dieux de la Licence bientôt disponible </a> <a href="./php/article.php?id=XXX"> <img src="images/sondage.jpg" alt="Allez-vous réussir votre année ?"><br> Résultat de notre sondage : allez-vous réussir votre année ? </a> </section> <section> <h2>Horoscope de la semaine</h2><p>Vous l'attendiez tous, voici l'horoscope du semestre pair de l'année 2019-2020. Sans surprise, il n'est pas terrible...</p> <table id="horoscope"> <tr> <td>Signe</td> <td>Date</td> <td>Votre horoscope</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&#9800; Bélier</td> <td>du 21 mars<br>au 19 avril</td> <td rowspan="4"> <p>Après des vacances bien méritées, l'année reprend sur les chapeaux de roues. Tous les signes sont concernés. </p> <p>Jupiter s'aligne avec Saturne, péremptoirement à Venus, et nous promet un semestre qui ne sera pas de tout repos. Février sera le mois le plus tranquille puisqu'il ne comporte que 29 jours.</p> <p>Les fins de mois seront douloureuses pour les natifs du 2e décan au moment où tomberont les tant-attendus résultats du module d'<em>Algorithmique et Structures de Données</em> du semestre 3.</p> </td> </tr> <tr> <td>&#9801; Taureau</td> <td>du 20 avril<br>au 20 mai</td> </tr> <tr> <td>...</td> <td>...</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&#9811; Poisson</td> <td>du 20 février<br>au 20 mars</td> </tr> </table> <p>Malgré cela, notre équipe d'astrologues de choc vous souhaite à tous un bon semestre, et bon courage pour le module de <em>Système et Programmation Système</em>.</p> </section></main><footer>&copy; Licence Informatique - Janvier 2020 - Tous droits réservés</footer></body></html>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clearly conveyed for understanding. I try to understand what is value of `$tag_file`, in shell it used as an array. You can remove all spaces between html tags with `perl -0777 -pe 's/(>)\s*(<)/$1$2/g' tmp_html`. But again you mention only particular tags in your message. It is not clear as $tag_file is unknown.

Comment: Your question would make sense if you use embedded system with scarce resources. Otherwise nowadays web server can be configured to _compress_ transmitted data to _shrink_ volume of traffic.

Comment: I specified that the $ tag_files variable contains the name of the specific tags obtained to tag_file = $ (cat $ VAR) $ VAR being a path to a file where the tags are written like this:
html
section
...
, tag will therefore take value of 1 "html" etc .. so I want to remove the spaces around the <html ...> tags

Comment: I'm just trying to do something simple in my spare time

Comment: @Antolife -- please edit your code and add a piece demonstrating how you obtain content `tag_file = $(cat $VAR)`. It would be a good idea to demonstrate an assignment to $VAR variable of some filename (may be comment is not bad idea). It would make the sample code more complete and you will avoid questions I asked _to pull out_ this information out of you.

Comment: @Antolife -- Is there a particular reason why you _wrap_ perl command into _shell_ script? It can be done with perl script itself? With perl script it will be much faster than make call to perl multiple times from shell script.

Comment: I changed but the problem does not come from there

Comment: Try `perl -0777 -pe 's/\s*(</?${tag}.*?>)\s*/\$1/g' tmp_html` instead. You have to put `\$1` otherwise shell will try to expand `$1` variable to it's value (unexpected behavior -- this variable intended for perl code not shell). Use of `\1` is [discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068840/what-is-the-difference-between-1-and-1-in-a-perl-regex).

Comment: Perhaps `perl -0777 -pe "s!\s*(</?${tag}\b.*?>)\s*!\$1!g" tmp_html` will be more precisely tuned. (note in previous post I forgot to escape forward slash `<\/${tag}...`).

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your perl line is your quoting; you used single quotes, which means you don't have to escape the Perl variables, but it also means the shell variable `${tag}` will be interpreted by Perl (where it's empty) not the shell. You can access shell variables more easily from Perl by either passing them as arguments or environment variables. You also didn't use the `-i` switch for in-place editing, so you just printed the changes to STDOUT.

With [ojo](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo) installed, you can do this with a proper HTML parser and thus not be susceptible to edge cases:

```
env tag=$tag perl -0777 -pi -CS -Mojo -e '$_ = x($_);
  $_->find($ENV{tag})->each(sub {
    $_->content($_->content =~ s/\A *//r =~ s/ *\z//r);
    my ($p, $n) = ($_->previous_node, $_->next_node);
    $p->content($p->content =~ s/ *\z//r) if defined $p and ($p->type eq "text" or $p->type eq "raw");
    $n->content($n->content =~ s/\A *//r) if defined $n and ($n->type eq "text" or $n->type eq "raw");
  })' tmp_html
```

The `-0777` switch ensures the file will be operated on in one step rather than by line, `-pi` wraps the code in a loop which will assign the input to `$_` and then update that file in-place with the resulting value of `$_`, and `-CS` ensures it will be decoded from UTF-8 to parse and encoded back after.

The `x` function from ojo creates a [Mojo::DOM](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::DOM) object, which can then find every instance of the requested tag and operate on it (which includes its contents and closing tag).

The substitution operations: `s/\A *//r` and `s/ *\z//r` remove all space characters from the beginning or end of the string respectively, and return the modified string (`/r` prevents it from operating in place, so you can use this with Mojo::DOM's content method). To instead remove any whitespace characters (including newlines), use `s/\A\s*//r` and `s/\s*\z//r`.

Comment: I'm new to perl; I therefore find it difficult to understand everything .. for the output stdout, I know I wanted to test in the terminal, could you tell me if possible with sed, or a simpler perl command, if there is. outside the perl, your explanation with env is clear I think I understand this point ; Thank you

Comment: If you remove `-i` (so just using `-p`) then it will output to STDOUT instead of editing in place. Same if you input from STDIN instead of passing the filename as an argument.

Comment: its ok ; and with sed ?

Comment: I don't know sed, but I've added some more explanation.

Comment: No problem thanks, and would you have a version with perl without ojo?

Comment: I would not try it, because operating on HTML with straight regexes is [extremely complicated to do correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5848200), and there aren't any simpler HTML parsers for the command line than ojo/Mojo::DOM. Your requirements are not that simple in actuality.

Comment: Yes, thats true

Answer (score 0):

After some communication with OP I hope that I properly understood the problem.

HTML tags is stored in separate file one per line (tag_file.txt), in separate file we have HTML webpage code (file.html).

The code should strip spaces in HTML webpage code (file.html) around tags [opening,closing] specified in tag file (tag_file.txt).

**NOTE:** processing done with perl script without shell's assistance (shortens processing time)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $tag_file    = 'tag_file.txt';
my $html_file   = 'file.html';

open my $fh_tag, '<', $tag_file         # open tag file
    or die "Couldn't open $tag_file: $!";

my @tags = <$fh_tag>;                   # read tags into array
chomp @tags;                            # remove eol from tag lines

close $fh_tag;                          # close tag file

open my $fh_html, '<', $html_file       # open html file
    or die "Couldn't open $html_file: $!";

my $html = do { local $/; <$fh_html> }; # read whole file into variable

close $fh_html;                         # close html file

# now make substitution for each read tag
for my $tag (@tags) { $html =~ s!\s*(</?$tag\s*.*?>)\s*!$1!g; }

say $html;
```

Content of **tag_file.txt**

```
html
head
body
section
```